# Websphere resource adapter,custom properties non editable

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

Installed Resource Adapter (a custom resource adapter) externally on Websphere 7

Opened Resource Adapter custom properties, image below

[image]

Trying to edit host property

[image]

But the field is not editable. Any reason why? I need to modify these properties through console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of editing custom properties of resource adapter. I opened the custom properties of J2C connection factory associated with the adapter and from there I could modify the properties and that works for me.

Screenshot
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have the administrative authority to make changes to Websphere Configuration.

To do this your userid need to have at least the **Configurator Role**  assigned.

You should communicate with your Websphere Administrator to take this authority.

Comment: I don't think its about privileges, the profile is open (I do not know the exact word for it). Because I can install and un-install the application, I installed the Resource adapters and stuff. So, I do not think its about privileges.